# How can I create a label filter for blogger that my readers could use? (Beginner Here)

Tags: html, label, blogger, url-encoding, blogspot

I have created a blog with blogger for distributing free templates - **https://templatemonstrosity.blogspot.in** But the thing is that I need to make it easier for my readers to search through my posts. I have a lot of labels and I think that it would b great if someone can help me to make a filterer like the one right here **https://btemplates.com/template-search/**. BTW. I am a complete beginner and it would be great if you make it easy to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple, Use keywords inside your posts and use blogger built-in search form with input types like radio checkbox and number to collecting keywords and searching for selected keywords.

Comment: Isn't there any widget or some script that I could just paste into my blog. Because I am really bad at coding myself and I don't know how to let the options lead to any specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Tag each template with the appropiated tags (that will serve as filters) and then just build dynamically with some Javascript a search query mixing tags:

```
/search/?q=label:LABEL1|label:LABEL2|label:LABEL3
```

Answer (score 0):

On the default page, on the left side, there is a bookmark "Labels"

Users may click there, and filter by the label that hey select.

After you add labels to your post, there is a yellow pentagonal pictogram on each of your post to add labels.